# Debian 10 samba (smb) share - cannot connect with any OS

Tags: linux, debian, samba, smb

I am attempting to deploy a samba share from a Debian 10 server, which I intend to use with both Windows, Mac OS X and other Debian 10 machines.

I have been at this for a few days now and not been able to connect to it with any machine, either public or private share.

Part of the problem is that I don't know what I should put in my samba config file.

What is the minimum amount of stuff I need to put in the config to get something basic working. (Public share, no security - I don't care about that at the moment.)

I have a theory that samba conflicts with nextcloud. I believe this is the case because when I run `smbtree` from another Linux machine on the network it picks up the IP address of the nextcloud server, which is (or was) running on a VM on the Debian 10 server.

I have now disabled this VM while I try to figure this out, but still had no success.

This is my output from `smbclient`, which I ran on the server, using the IP of the server. (itself)

```
smbclient -L 192.168.1.111 -U smbuser
Unable to initialize messaging context
Enter WORKGROUP\smbuser's password: 

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    share           Disk      
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Samba 4.9.5-Debian)
Reconnecting with SMB1 for workgroup listing.
smbXcli_negprot_smb1_done: No compatible protocol selected by server.
protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_NETWORK_RESPONSE
Failed to connect with SMB1 -- no workgroup available
```

Here is the contents of my `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

```
[global]

   log level = 3

   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   hosts allow = 192.168.1.
   security = user
   max protocol = SMB3
   min protocol = SMB2

   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

   max log size = 1000

   logging = file

   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d

   server role = standalone server

   obey pam restrictions = yes


   unix password sync = yes

   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .


   pam password change = yes

   map to guest = bad user
   usershare allow guests = yes

[share]
  path = /smbshare
  writable = yes
  create mode = 0770
  directory mode = 0770
  share modes = yes
  guest ok = no
  valid users = @smbgroup
```

This is my `testparm`

```
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Registered MSG_REQ_POOL_USAGE
Registered MSG_REQ_DMALLOC_MARK and LOG_CHANGED
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[share]"
Unknown parameter encountered: "share modes"
Ignoring unknown parameter "share modes"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

# Global parameters
[global]
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    logging = file
    map to guest = Bad User
    max log size = 1000
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    security = USER
    server min protocol = SMB2
    server role = standalone server
    unix password sync = Yes
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
    hosts allow = 192.168.1.


[share]
    create mask = 0770
    directory mask = 0770
    path = /smbshare
    read only = No
    valid users = @smbgroup
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm quite new to this so I don't really know how to debug anything. I restarted the smbd and nmbd services, and checked the status. There were not obvious problems.

I also run an nfs share on this machine, and that works fine. I assume this doesn't cause any conflict.

## Logs

I am still playing with the config file to try and get something working... here's what it looked like when these logs were generated.

```
[global]

   log level = 3

   workgroup = WORKGROUP

   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

   max log size = 1000

   logging = file

   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d

   server role = standalone server

   obey pam restrictions = yes

   unix password sync = yes

   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

   pam password change = yes

   map to guest = bad user

   usershare allow guests = yes


[Share]
  path = /smbshare
  writable = yes
  create mode = 0770
  directory mode = 0770
  guest ok = yes
```

first log...

```
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.940912,  3] ../lib/util/access.c:365(allow_access)
  Allowed connection from 192.168.1.110 (192.168.1.110)
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.940997,  3] ../source3/smbd/service.c:603(make_connection_snum)
  make_connection_snum: Connect path is '/tmp' for service [IPC$]
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.941050,  3] ../source3/smbd/vfs.c:113(vfs_init_default)
  Initialising default vfs hooks
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.941081,  3] ../source3/smbd/vfs.c:139(vfs_init_custom)
  Initialising custom vfs hooks from [/[Default VFS]/]
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.941226,  3] ../source3/smbd/service.c:849(make_connection_snum)
  debian (ipv4:192.168.1.110:33412) connect to service IPC$ initially as user nobody (uid=65534, gid=65534) (pid 3744)
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.943097,  3] ../source3/rpc_server/srv_pipe.c:751(api_pipe_bind_req)
  api_pipe_bind_req: srvsvc -> srvsvc rpc service
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.943132,  3] ../source3/rpc_server/srv_pipe.c:356(check_bind_req)
  check_bind_req for srvsvc context_id=0
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.943158,  3] ../source3/rpc_server/srv_pipe.c:399(check_bind_req)
  check_bind_req: srvsvc -> srvsvc rpc service
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.944207,  3] ../source3/rpc_server/srv_pipe.c:1531(api_rpcTNP)
  api_rpcTNP: rpc command: SRVSVC_NETSHAREENUMALL
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.944286,  1] ../source3/printing/printer_list.c:234(printer_list_get_last_refresh)
  Failed to fetch record!
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.944309,  1] ../source3/smbd/server_reload.c:64(delete_and_reload_printers)
  pcap cache not loaded
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.945757,  3] ../source3/smbd/service.c:1129(close_cnum)
  debian (ipv4:192.168.1.110:33412) closed connection to service IPC$
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.949744,  3] ../source3/smbd/server_exit.c:237(exit_server_common)
  Server exit (NT_STATUS_END_OF_FILE)
```

and another

```
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.940912,  3] ../lib/util/access.c:365(allow_access)
  Allowed connection from 192.168.1.110 (192.168.1.110)
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.940997,  3] ../source3/smbd/service.c:603(make_connection_snum)
  make_connection_snum: Connect path is '/tmp' for service [IPC$]
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.941050,  3] ../source3/smbd/vfs.c:113(vfs_init_default)
  Initialising default vfs hooks
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.941081,  3] ../source3/smbd/vfs.c:139(vfs_init_custom)
  Initialising custom vfs hooks from [/[Default VFS]/]
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.941226,  3] ../source3/smbd/service.c:849(make_connection_snum)
  debian (ipv4:192.168.1.110:33412) connect to service IPC$ initially as user nobody (uid=65534, gid=65534) (pid 3744)
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.943097,  3] ../source3/rpc_server/srv_pipe.c:751(api_pipe_bind_req)
  api_pipe_bind_req: srvsvc -> srvsvc rpc service
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.943132,  3] ../source3/rpc_server/srv_pipe.c:356(check_bind_req)
  check_bind_req for srvsvc context_id=0
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.943158,  3] ../source3/rpc_server/srv_pipe.c:399(check_bind_req)
  check_bind_req: srvsvc -> srvsvc rpc service
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.944207,  3] ../source3/rpc_server/srv_pipe.c:1531(api_rpcTNP)
  api_rpcTNP: rpc command: SRVSVC_NETSHAREENUMALL
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.944286,  1] ../source3/printing/printer_list.c:234(printer_list_get_last_refresh)
  Failed to fetch record!
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.944309,  1] ../source3/smbd/server_reload.c:64(delete_and_reload_printers)
  pcap cache not loaded
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.945757,  3] ../source3/smbd/service.c:1129(close_cnum)
  debian (ipv4:192.168.1.110:33412) closed connection to service IPC$
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.949744,  3] ../source3/smbd/server_exit.c:237(exit_server_common)
  Server exit (NT_STATUS_END_OF_FILE)
root@proton:/var/log/samba# cat log.192.168.1.110 
[2020/08/12 13:34:30.779090,  3] ../source3/smbd/oplock.c:1389(init_oplocks)
  init_oplocks: initializing messages.
[2020/08/12 13:34:30.779168,  3] ../source3/smbd/process.c:1956(process_smb)
  Transaction 0 of length 222 (0 toread)
[2020/08/12 13:34:30.779370,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_negprot.c:294(smbd_smb2_request_process_negprot)
  Selected protocol SMB3_11
[2020/08/12 13:34:30.782362,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'gssapi_spnego' registered
[2020/08/12 13:34:30.782395,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5' registered
[2020/08/12 13:34:30.782415,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5_sasl' registered
[2020/08/12 13:34:30.782433,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'spnego' registered
[2020/08/12 13:34:30.782451,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'schannel' registered
[2020/08/12 13:34:30.782469,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'naclrpc_as_system' registered
[2020/08/12 13:34:30.782487,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'sasl-EXTERNAL' registered
[2020/08/12 13:34:30.782505,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp' registered
[2020/08/12 13:34:30.782523,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp_resume_ccache' registered
[2020/08/12 13:34:30.782541,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'http_basic' registered
[2020/08/12 13:34:30.782559,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'http_ntlm' registered
[2020/08/12 13:34:30.782577,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'http_negotiate' registered
[2020/08/12 13:34:30.782599,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'krb5' registered
[2020/08/12 13:34:30.782618,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'fake_gssapi_krb5' registered
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.934118,  3] ../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_util.c:72(debug_ntlmssp_flags)
  Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62088215
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.935422,  3] ../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_server.c:552(ntlmssp_server_preauth)
  Got user=[user] domain=[WORKGROUP] workstation=[DEBIAN] len1=24 len2=306
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.935480,  3] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:3872(lp_load_ex)
  lp_load_ex: refreshing parameters
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.935564,  3] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:548(init_globals)
  Initialising global parameters
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.935674,  3] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2786(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[global]"
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.935928,  2] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2803(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[Share]"
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.936030,  3] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:1621(lp_add_ipc)
  adding IPC service
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.936070,  3] ../source3/auth/auth.c:189(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Checking password for unmapped user [WORKGROUP]\[user]@[DEBIAN] with the new password interface
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.936093,  3] ../source3/auth/auth.c:192(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  mapped user is: [WORKGROUP]\[user]@[DEBIAN]
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.936302,  3] ../source3/passdb/lookup_sid.c:1680(get_primary_group_sid)
  Forcing Primary Group to 'Domain Users' for user
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.936461,  3] ../libcli/auth/ntlm_check.c:403(ntlm_password_check)
  ntlm_password_check: NTLMv2 password check failed
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.936488,  3] ../libcli/auth/ntlm_check.c:449(ntlm_password_check)
  ntlm_password_check: Lanman passwords NOT PERMITTED for user user
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.936519,  3] ../libcli/auth/ntlm_check.c:595(ntlm_password_check)
  ntlm_password_check: LM password and LMv2 failed for user user, and NT MD4 password in LM field not permitted
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.936748,  2] ../source3/auth/auth.c:334(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Authentication for user [user] -> [user] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD, authoritative=1
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.936834,  2] ../auth/auth_log.c:610(log_authentication_event_human_readable)
  Auth: [SMB2,(null)] user [WORKGROUP]\[user] at [Wed, 12 Aug 2020 13:34:31.936815 BST] with [NTLMv2] status [NT_STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD] workstation [DEBIAN] remote host [ipv4:192.168.1.110:33412] mapped to [WORKGROUP]\[user]. local host [ipv4:192.168.1.111:445] 
  {"timestamp": "2020-08-12T13:34:31.936924+0100", "type": "Authentication", "Authentication": {"version": {"major": 1, "minor": 0}, "status": "NT_STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD", "localAddress": "ipv4:192.168.1.111:445", "remoteAddress": "ipv4:192.168.1.110:33412", "serviceDescription": "SMB2", "authDescription": null, "clientDomain": "WORKGROUP", "clientAccount": "user", "workstation": "DEBIAN", "becameAccount": null, "becameDomain": null, "becameSid": null, "mappedAccount": "user", "mappedDomain": "WORKGROUP", "netlogonComputer": null, "netlogonTrustAccount": null, "netlogonNegotiateFlags": "0x00000000", "netlogonSecureChannelType": 0, "netlogonTrustAccountSid": null, "passwordType": "NTLMv2", "duration": 2937}}
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.937017,  3] ../auth/gensec/spnego.c:1414(gensec_spnego_server_negTokenTarg_step)
  gensec_spnego_server_negTokenTarg_step: SPNEGO(ntlmssp) login failed: NT_STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.937072,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3195(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE] || at ../source3/smbd/smb2_sesssetup.c:137
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.938149,  3] ../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_util.c:72(debug_ntlmssp_flags)
  Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62088215
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.939042,  3] ../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_server.c:552(ntlmssp_server_preauth)
  Got user=[] domain=[] workstation=[] len1=0 len2=0
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.939078,  3] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:3872(lp_load_ex)
  lp_load_ex: refreshing parameters
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.939142,  3] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:548(init_globals)
  Initialising global parameters
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.939241,  3] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2786(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[global]"
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.939493,  2] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2803(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[Share]"
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.939582,  3] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:1621(lp_add_ipc)
  adding IPC service
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.939611,  3] ../source3/auth/auth.c:189(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Checking password for unmapped user []\[]@[] with the new password interface
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.939630,  3] ../source3/auth/auth.c:192(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  mapped user is: []\[]@[]
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.939656,  3] ../source3/auth/auth.c:256(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  auth_check_ntlm_password: anonymous authentication for user [] succeeded
[2020/08/12 13:34:31.939695,  3] ../auth/auth_log.c:610(log_authentication_event_human_readable)
  Auth: [SMB2,(null)] user []\[] at [Wed, 12 Aug 2020 13:34:31.939680 BST] with [No-Password] status [NT_STATUS_OK] workstation [] remote host [ipv4:192.168.1.110:33412] became [PROTON]\[nobody] [S-1-5-21-535964934-3898815840-3937253692-501]. local host [ipv4:192.168.1.111:445] 
  {"timestamp": "2020-08-12T13:34:31.939739+0100", "type": "Authentication", "Authentication": {"version": {"major": 1, "minor": 0}, "status": "NT_STATUS_OK", "localAddress": "ipv4:192.168.1.111:445", "remoteAddress": "ipv4:192.168.1.110:33412", "serviceDescription": "SMB2", "authDescription": null, "clientDomain": "", "clientAccount": "", "workstation": "", "becameAccount": "nobody", "becameDomain": "PROTON", "becameSid": "S-1-5-21-535964934-3898815840-3937253692-501", "mappedAccount": "", "mappedDomain": "", "netlogonComputer": null, "netlogonTrustAccount": null, "netlogonNegotiateFlags": "0x00000000", "netlogonSecureChannelType": 0, "netlogonTrustAccountSid": null, "passwordType": "No-Password", "duration": 1726}}
```

Comment: add to the smbclient command `-m SMB2` and try it also like `smbclient -L 192.168.1.111 -m SMB2`

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro `smbclient -L 192.168.1.111 -m SMB2 -U smbuser` still prints the same result: Failed to connect with SMB1 ?

Comment: Check the log files, `/var/log/samba/log.%m`. You've already set a high level of logging, `log level = 3` so there's going to be a lot of detail. Post the logs if they don't help you to find a solution.

Comment: @Krackout see above

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice. I see in the logs that SMB3 is selected. As a first step I suggest sticking with SMB2, so `max protocol = SMB2` in conf. Try it that way, post logs after the change to check further.

Comment: @Krackout no difference I'm sad to report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured out the problem: You mention you want no security, so I guess you didn't add any user and ran `smbpasswd`. User `user` may be the user you login to your Debian system.

Yet on your config you have `security = user`, which means user authentication.

So for no authentication you only need:

```
[global]
        map to guest = Bad User

[Share]
        path = /smbshare
        read only = no
        guest ok = yes
        guest only = yes
```

(I checked [samba wiki](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_a_Standalone_Server) for the configuration needed)

Comment: I actually added a user called `smbuser`... See this is why I'm somewhat confused. Some info online suggests adding a user and using that user as a guest effectively, some guides permit actual real user accounts such as the one I have on my linux box (ecb).

Comment: It still isn't working by the way

Comment: Ok, it is now working! I think it just takes a while to update

Comment: (at least it is working on Linux systems)

Comment: And I can connect on OS X - thanks for your help, assuming the Windows system works as well then I'm all good

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is the minimum you need for a guest only share, that doesn't use SMBv1:

```
[global]
    security = USER
    map to guest = Bad User
    client min protocol = SMB2
    server min protocol = SMB2

[share]
    path = /smbshare
    read only = No
    guest ok = yes
    guest only = yes
```

When you have got that working and then want authenticated users, read 'man smb.conf'

Comment: An additional line is visible in `testparm`... the line is `idmap config * : backend = tdb`. Any idea why this is here?

Comment: You can ignore that, it is an artefact from the domain member setup, it is one of those things that are annoying, but not annoying enough for someone to fix.